# Find if a string contains a specific query string and return its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have pagination links set-up like this:

http://localhost/?page=2
http://localhost/?page=3

They are wrapped in Anchor links as the HREF attribute. I want to know how can I check first if the HREF attribute for a given ANCHOR contains the query string "page" case sensitive, and if it exists return its number the value after page=

Please give me a straightforward example on this, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function getPageNumber( $obj ){
  if( $obj.filter('a[href*=page\=]').length )
    return $obj.attr('href').split('page=')[1];  
  else
    return false;
}
```

Then with:

```
<a id="foo" href="http://localhost/?page=3">Foo</a>
<a id="bar" href="http://localhost/?page=4">Bar</a>
<a id="baz" href="http://localhost/?Page=5">Baz</a> <!--- capital P --->
```

You'd get:

```
var result = getPageNumber( $('a#foo') ); // returns 3
var result = getPageNumber( $('a#bar') ); // returns 4
var result = getPageNumber( $('a#baz') ); // returns false (case sensitive)
```

Of course it would be easy to write the function to take a plain DOM object, or an ID, or whatever else you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a point to the anchor tab and the format given by you is consistent, then it can be done with something as given below

```
var a = document.getElementById("#myanchor");
if(/[\?&]page=/.test(a.href){
    alert("parameter page present");
}
```

Here we are looking for the parameter `page` with the help of [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) [regular expression.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var href = this.attr("href");
    if(href.match(/page/)) {
        pageNumber = parseInt(href.split('=')[1]);
        doSomething(this, pageNumber); //this is the jQuery element
    }
});
```